# how to make string not show

Tags: java, if-statement

compiles perfectly but i just want to know how to make unwated coins to not appear. 
ie. user input: 9.65

so output would be:

### 4 toonies 1 loony 2 quarters 1 dimes 1 nickel

buy mine shows this:

You entered the amount 9 dollars and 65 cents.

To make up this amount, use

### 4 toonies 1 loony 2 quarters 6 dime 13 nickels 15 pennies

End of processing

> 

edited:

```
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane; // Needed for JOptionPane
    import java.util.Scanner;

/**
  This program is for question 1.
  need to use echo and make only needed coins appear and also space between lines
*/
```

package test;

```
public class coincounterr {
    public static void main (String[] args){
        //Declare variables        
        String input; //to ask user an amount of money        
        double money; //money user types in        
        int dollars;        
        double cents;        
        long t, l, q, d, n, p;
        final int QUARTERS = 25;
        final int DIME = 10;
        final int NICKEL = 5;
        final int PENNIES = 1;

        //Ask user for an amount of money
        input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter any amount of money in $.");
        money = Double.parseDouble(input);

        //use println to display the end result
        dollars = (int) money;
        long cent = Math.round((money-Math.floor(money))*100);
        System.out.println("You entered the amount " + dollars + " dollars and " + cent + " cents.\n");
        t = dollars/2; //2 dollars
        l = dollars%2; //1 dollar
        q = cent/25; //25 cents
        d = (cent%25)/10; //10 cents
        n = (cent - (q*25)-(d*10))/5; //5 cents
        p = cent - (q*25)-(d*10)-(n*5); //1cent 

        // output for toonies and loonies
        System.out.println("To make up this amount, use \n");
        if ( t<= 0)
            System.out.println();
        else if ( t > 1)
            System.out.println(+t+" toonies \n");
        else if ( t <= 1)
            System.out.println(+t+" toony \n");
        if (l<=0)
            System.out.println();
        else if ( l > 1)
            System.out.println( + l + " loonies \n");
        else if ( l <= 1)
            System.out.println( +l+ " loony \n");


        //use if statement for QUARTERS
        if (q <= 0)
            System.out.println();
        else if (cent >= QUARTERS) //25 cents
            System.out.println( +q+ " quarters \n"); 
        if (d <= 0)
            System.out.println();                    
        else if ( cent >= DIME )
            System.out.println ( +d+ " dime \n");
        if (n <= 0)
            System.out.println();
        else if ( cent >= NICKEL)
            System.out.println( +n+ " nickels\n");
        if (p <= 0)
            System.out.println();                      
        else if ( cent >= PENNIES)
            System.out.println( +p+ " pennies\n");

        System.out.println("End of processing");
    }
}
```

Comment: I could not understand your requirements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `if (n > 0)` before printing "unnecessary" coins. I won't post code so that you can keep practising ;)

EDIT: big hint:

```
else if (cent <= NICKEL) {
    if (n > 0)
        System.out.println(n+" nickels");
}
```

EDIT2: There is a problem in your computation: let's suppose you have 65 cents (`cent = 65`):

```
d = cent/10; // 6
n = cent/5;  // 13, when what you want is probably 1
```

You're forgetting to substract the amount previously counted in `d`: if you have 65 cents and decided to get `65 / 10 = 6` coins of 10 cents, the remainder is 5 cents. You should work on the remainders at each step.

Good luck!

Comment: hey sorry i dont understand.. new to this java

Comment: It's not related to Java, but to general algorithmics. I'll edit my answer to make it (a little bit) clearer.

Comment: sorry idk how to make it like code format for this website

Comment: @BithiahBids, click the [`help`](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) link under the `Add Comment` button, it will show you how to properly use formatting.
Did you compile your code and test it? The use here is to show what you already did when asking a question. I don't think your code will compile as-is. Fix the obvious errors and update your questions before when can help! :)

Comment: hey thanks. the code given above compiles perfectly the only thing i am having problem is with the output. lets say the user enter 7.23.. so i need 3 toonies 1 loony 2 dimes and 3 pennies. but mine shows every single coin. so i dont know what to do

Comment: @BithiahBids as it sounds like school work, use your imagination (and a couple `if` ;)) to avoid printing things like `0 nickels`. Like what I said in my answer: `if (n > 0) println(n+" nickels");` will not print anything if `n` is `0`...

Comment: @BithiahBids Re-reading your question, it seems there is a problem in your computation then. I thought it initially showed the zeroes. I'll further edit my answer then.

Comment: heyy thanks i figured it out and got.. but right now idk how to deal with the alignment..can u check out my edited code?

Comment: @BithiahBids what do you mean by "alignment"?

Comment: Sorry I'm new to this so maybe I'm not even saying the right thing. Like the output. I want it to be: just one spacing but sometimes it comes out double spacing or so

Comment: @bumblebee You realize that you deleted your entire question??? If you're afraid that somebody might copy your code, post at least the unrelevant parts that could help us to help you. If your problem is on sensitive matter, don't post it on the Internet...